# Additional data passed via Jquery BlueImp File Upload Plugin not getting correctly at Server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using Blueimp jQuery File Upload Plugin to upload single and multiple images.

Here I want to pass some additional data along with images to server like caption,share option etc. I searched site and found how to sent multiple files in a single ajax request and also passed additional data to server. But the problem is, when I added a textarea in template for capturing caption of images in template the data is getting like [object Object] in server. But when I pass only caption I am getting it as array.

Here is the code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    disableImageResize: false,
    autoUpload: false,
    singleFileUploads:false,
    url: jQuery('#site').val()+'UserPhotos/upload?Token='+jQuery('#token').val()
    }).bind('fileuploadsubmit', function(e, data) { 
    //binding 
    var photo_share = jQuery('#photo_share').val();
    var public = 1;
    //serializing the captions for photos to be send to server
    var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
    if (inputs.filter('[value=""]').first().focus().length) {
        data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
        return false;
    }
    data.formData = {
        'caption': inputs.serializeArray(),
        'photo_share':photo_share,
        'public':public
    };

});
```

HTML:

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <textarea  name="caption[]" placeholder="Enter caption" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
        </td>
    // ...
```

Any help to get this passed to server properly and parse the same?

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: simply use serializeArray() of form id in "fileuploadsubmit" bind of fileupload function.Data will be passed to server correctly.

```
var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
                if (inputs.filter('[value=""]').first().focus().length) {
                    data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
                    return false;
                }
data.formData = jQuery('#fileupload').serializeArray();
```